# Is there a handler for after the grid has finished loading in SmartGWT?

Tags: smartgwt

I want to do something after my `listgrid` has finished all its data, but I am not sure if there is a handler out there to do this? I tried to use `DataArrivedHandler`, but that is not correct because it fires way too many times as data are loading. Is there something i can do to achieve this?

Comment: You may be fetching the grid more than once because DataArrivedHandler only fires once per fetch, ¿could we see the properties of your grid and the code that fetches your data?